# How can i install android sdk set up revision 4 and launch emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have downloaded "android-sdk_r04-windows", after unzip I tried to install 
 "SDK Setup.exe", but i got following error and nothing was installed.

Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 4
Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected 1357f66cb935fc6ae31ba656024a81fe787349c9, got 54a9ee4a067aaa03a6703e0e46d64b62e68ed994.
Skipping 'SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 1'; it depends on 'Android SDK Tools, revision 4' which was not installed.

Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 1
Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected b04453e6f0f0d0df16740e360114c559092dfaf4, got 992f81247809b37ac0ccc2434474aa628763baef.
Skipping 'SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1'; it depends on 'Android SDK Tools, revision 4' which was not installed.

Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1
Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected 255781ebe4509d9707d0e77edda2815e2bc216e6, got 27a1c8bc9d2ce5e1cc4b2547114e6e64f70cbabb.
Skipping 'SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1'; it depends on 'Android SDK Tools, revision 4' which was not installed.

Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1
Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected aeb623217ff88b87216d6eb7dbc846ed53f68f57, got 797384e01074c8a6446731143f7987fd6a6fc64b.

can anyone please help me ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting checksum failures then your download didn't complete successfully. Try downloading again. If you have to, use a download manager. Firefox has several download manager extensions that are good.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with wrong checksums. I've disabled my antivirus (AVG) and they downloaded successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I am running AVG Antivirus and was getting invalid checksum errors as well. I disabled:

- [Resident Shield](http://www.ehow.com/how_5052104_disable-avg-antivirus.html)
- Link Scanner
- Online Shield
- Anti-Rootkit

You probably don't need to disable all of those, but disabling just the Resident Shield did *not* work for me.

+1 to chchrist's post for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install SDKs for Android it to use Eclipse ADT plugin.

This way you only need to:

1. Download and unpack SDK
2. Install ADT Eclipse plugin
3. Point ADT to SDK location (`Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK location`)
4. Use `Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager` to install selected SDK revisions.

That's it.